# What am I doing wrong with my Android GridView?

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-gridview

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong with my Android GridView. I am pulling data out of the SQLite database, and returning a cursor to the adapter, but it is definitely not lining up properly when it is rendered. Here is what I have.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@color/app_name"
                android:textSize="38sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/top_right_info_board" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/row_of_stats"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**data_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_textview"
        android:background="@color/RED"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data01_textview"
        android:background="@color/DARKVIOLET"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data02_textview"
        android:background="@color/YELLOWGREEN"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data03_textview"
        android:background="@color/LIGHTPINK"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data04_textview"
        android:background="@color/MIDNIGHTBLUE"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data05_textview"
        android:background="@color/PALEVIOLETRED"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data06_textview"
        android:background="@color/AQUA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data07_textview"
        android:background="@color/YELLOWGREEN"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data08_textview"
        android:background="@color/BLUEVIOLET"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
dataCursor = myDBHelper.getDataCursor();
String[] fromColumns = {"_id","data01","data02","data03","data04","data05","data06","data07","data08"};
int[] toViews = {R.id.id_textview, R.id.data01_textview, R.id.data02_textview, R.id.data03_textview, R.id.data04_textview, R.id.data05_textview, R.id.data06_textview, R.id.data07_textview, R.id.data08_textview};
SimpleCursorAdapter mySimpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.data_row, dataCursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);
GridView myGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.row_of_stats);
myGridView.setAdapter(mySimpleCursorAdapter);
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

I tried to use the `android:numColumns="9"`, but this is what happened after that:

[image]

What I want it to look like is this:

[image]

I accomplished this final, attractive, layout using a ScrollView and TableLayout, but it was really kludgy and **VERY** slow, so I would MUCH rather stick with the GridView adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a data table; you don't want a `GridView`.

`GridView` is used when every cell is (usually) the same type.  If you had a bunch of thumbnail images, the grid would make sense whether it had two columns or four columns.

In your case, each column represents something different from the column next to it, so a `GridView` doesn't make sense here.

You can start by just changing your `GridView` to a `ListView`.  Your data row layout is already in a horizontal orientation, you have a `CursorAdapter` doing the right thing.  Just changing `GridView` to `ListView` will get you in the right direction.

Then you're going to want to start playing with row layouts.  A good start would be to give your `TextView` "cells" all the same weight along with a `minWidth` value.

The final problem you'll have is what to do when the table is wider than the device screen, even after you've compressed the row to it's smallest readable width.  A super-simple solution would be to have left/right buttons.  When the user presses the button to go right, you set your adapter to put `visibility="gone"` on the first `TextView` in the layout, which makes the table jump to the left.  If the user pressed right again, you set the first *two* `TextView`s to `visibility="gone"`.  You get the idea.

I was working on a project for a data table where each list item view was a `HorizontalScrollView` containing a horizontal `LinearLayout` with `TextView` cells, like you have.  The trick was that I captured the horizontal scroll events of one row, then propagated them to all the rows, so the rows would all synchronously scroll horizontally, giving the effect of a two-way scroll.  And of course, because of the recycling on each of the rows, the (vertical) scroll performance was really good.  Let me know if you're interested in seeing that.

Comment: Well, that's just absolutely beautiful ... thank you! I made the changes you suggested and everything lays out very nicely now. It's odd, I have been looking for a way to make a simple data table in Android for quite a while now, with not much success. Many people suggested GridView, but I just didn't feel that was correct, but I went with the majority view (so to speak). I'm still not sure why something that is so easy in web development, is so difficult in Android. Again, thank you so much!